# How to fetch particular info in JSON

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

This is my JSON data which is I am getting from the server **{"success":1,"message":"Thanks for the register."}**. I want to extract this **1** from the **success**. Please help me how should I so this.

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            try {
                JSONObject reader= new JSONObject(result);
                JSONObject obj1 = reader.getJSONObject("success");
                String check = obj1.toString();


                if (check.equals("3")) {

                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "You are already registered with us",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    emailText.setText("");

                   Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this,ReferalIdActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use reader.getInt("success");

Answer (score 0):

the `success` field is an `Integer` not a `JsonObject`, you need to read it like this :  `reader.getInt("success");`